# List of not supported functions in file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

The following code is giving me a list of all functions, which are currently not supported by Apache POI:

```
Collection<String> unsupportedFuncs = WorkbookEvaluator.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
  for (String unsupportedFunc : unsupportedFuncs) {
  System.out.println(unsupportedFunc);
}
```

I'm more interested in the functions/formulas which are not supported within a specific excel-file. Is there a way to get a list of those functions?

I already did this "manually" by going through all cells of all sheets, checking if it is of type formula, adding it to a list and adjusting this list to the one above by erasing the duplicates (see Project "UnsupportedFormulas" on my GitHub: https://github.com/Joey73/poi).

Isn't there an easier and better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On of the [Apache POI examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/formula/CheckFunctionsSupported.java) does exactly what you want

The javadoc for the CheckFunctionsSupported describes it as:

> Attempts to re-evaluate all the formulas in the workbook, and reports what (if any) formula functions used are not (currently) supported by Apache POI.
>
> This provides examples of how to evaluate formulas in excel files using Apache POI, along with how to handle errors whilst doing so.

You can find this program in the POI Examples jar, or you can grab [the source from SVN](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/formula/CheckFunctionsSupported.java). Run that against your file, and the output'll tell you any formula functions used are not supported, and what formula evaluation errors encountered